# Table View Mask not sizing correctly?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am attempting to round the top corners of my table view using a mask. I added an extension to the UITableView to do so.

```swift
extension UITableView {


func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
}
```

In the ViewDidLoad function, I call,

```swift
tableView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 15)
```

However, the while the Table View's top are rounded, the mask seems to be the incorrect size. The content of the table view is dynamic, as cells are added and removed. The first cell shows up properly, but when I scroll the the correct amount of cells show but they can't be seen. I think that the mask is being drawn to the table view size before cells are added - I have tried moving the function to

```swift
func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
```

But that does not change anything. Also, I have tried adding the function to  after the data is loaded, which still does not do anything.

[image: Table View with Wrong Masking]

Comment: add clipsToBounds property in your tableview.

Comment: @Tann I have tried that, right after the functions that rounds the corners. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, working

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        tableView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 15)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

        return cell
    }
}

extension UITableView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                            byRoundingCorners: corners,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = rect
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem !